# wrong path in copy command in dockerfile in azure pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I use azure devops pipeline to build jar and put it to docker image.
I use maven to build jar and put jar and dependencies to folder /componentA/target/container
Pom file - /componemtA/pom.xml
Docker file - /componentA/docker/Dockerfile

My pipeline yuml file is

```
......
stages:
 - stage: BUILD
    jobs:
      - job: BUILD_JAR_AND_IMAGE
        steps:
          - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
....
          - task: Maven@3
......
          - task: Docker@2
             inputs:
              command: login
              containerRegistry: xxxx
  
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: Build an image
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'xxx'
              repository: '$(image_name)'
              command: 'build'
              Dockerfile: '$(component_dir)/docker/Dockerfile'
              tags: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

My docker file is:

```
.....
COPY /componentA/target/container /opt
....
```

And I get error
2021-01-12T00:04:43.9376526Z Step 2/19 : COPY /componentA/target/container /opt
2021-01-12T00:04:43.9431565Z COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder630817503/componentA/target/container: no such file or directory
2021-01-12T00:04:43.9501516Z ##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder630817503/besReportService/target/container: no such file or directory
2021-01-12T00:04:43.9717162Z ##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

copy command starts in **var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder630817503** instead of **/home/vsts/work/1/s**

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have `.dockerignore` file that ignored the directory you was trying to COPY.

Check the following issue to see whether it helps you:

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/90